# Disable automatic test execution for some tests unless those are explicitly requested

Tags: python, unit-testing, nosetests

I have a few very slow tests and many short unittests. I would like to be able to run only the short unittests with plain `nosetests` command and if I decide it's time to run the slow tests, to be able to call them explicitly.

#### What I'd like to be able to do:

- run unittests but **not the slow tests**

  ```
  $ nosetests
  ```

  No special command is used - anyone who enters `nosetests` just out of curiosity would be satisfied in a few seconds.
- explicitly request the slow tests:

  ```
  $ nosetests --somehow-magicaly-invoke-slow-tests
  ```

  There is no ambiguity - I want the slow tests (or unittests and the slow test - it does not matter)

#### What have I tried:

I tried using `nose.plugins.attrib`:

```
from nose.plugins.attrib import attr
import time

@attr('slow')
def test_slow_one():
    time.sleep(5)

def test_unittest():
    assert True
```

but it in fact does almost the opposite of what I'm trying to accomplish - I have to specify extra commandline parameters to **not run** the slow tests. The commands are:

Run unittests but **not the slow tests**

```
$ nosetests -v -a '!slow'
test_a.test_unittest ... ok
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s
OK
```

explicitly request the slow tests:

```
$ nosetests -v -a 'slow'
test_a.test_slow_one ... ok
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 5.005s
OK
```

And to make things worse, when someone runs just

```
$ nosetests -v
test_a.test_slow_one ... ok
test_a.test_unittest ... ok
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 5.007s
OK
```

**all tests** including the slow ones will be run.

### The question:

Is there a way to disable some tests so they won't get called with plain `nosetests` command, but can be run with some additional commandline parameters?

#### Current "solution":

I just moved all slow tests into separate files and named the files `check_*.py` instead of `test_*.py` so `nosetests` won't pick them up. When I want to run the slow tests I just specify the whole path to the `check_*.py` files, something like:

```
$ nosetests test/check_foo.py test/check_bar.py [...]
```

which is not very elegant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily use [`unittest.skipUnless()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.skipUnless) to that effect.

### Skipping single tests

Simply [decorate](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators) the methods of your test case that you want to conditionally skip with

```
@unittest.skipUnless(condition, reason)
```

For example, you could check for an **environment variable** `SLOW_TESTS` that you simply don't set in your automated CI environment, but set if and when you want to run your slow tests locally:

```
import os
import time
import unittest


SLOW_TESTS = os.environ.get('SLOW_TESTS', False)


    class TestFoo(unittest.TestCase):

        def test_upper(self):
            self.assertEqual('foo'.upper(), 'FOO')

        @unittest.skipUnless(SLOW_TESTS, "slow test")
        def test_something_slow(self):
            time.sleep(5)
            self.assertTrue(True)
```

Output for a regular run:

```
$ nosetests -v
test_something_slow (test_foo.TestFoo) ... SKIP: slow test
test_upper (test_foo.TestFoo) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.002s

OK (SKIP=1)
```

Output when setting the environment variable:

```
$ SLOW_TESTS=1 nosetests -v
test_something_slow (test_foo.TestFoo) ... ok
test_upper (test_foo.TestFoo) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 5.003s

OK
```

*(Note that the Nose testrunner still says `Ran 2 tests` even though it skipped one. The skipped tests are indicated at the very end with `(SKIP=n)` and in the test results with `SKIP` or `S` in non-verbose mode).*

Of course you could invert the behavior by using [`skipIf()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.skipIf) using an environment variable like `FAST_TESTS` that you set in your CI setup.

### Skipping an entire TestCase

If you want to skip *all* tests in a TestCase that you know to be slow or have some heavy setup, it may be more convenient to call [`TestCase.skipTest()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.skipTest) explicitly (you can also do that from a single test if you need more fine grained control):

```
class TestFoo(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        if not SLOW_TESTS:
            self.skipTest("slow test")
        # some expensive setup
```

See [Skipping tests and expected failures](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#skipping-tests-and-expected-failures) for more details on skipping tests.

Comment: Thanks, this definitely works - but unfortunately it's not the "simple and elegant" solution I was looking for. This is a bit of a "do it yourself" solution, while I was hoping for some hidden feature of `nosetest`.. But it clearly solves my problem - I'll accept tomorrow if no better answer shows up.